# Prove for composition of step function

Tags: analysis, proof-verification

My Lemma is: If f is a step function and F is a function defined on set R, so that F(0)=0, than $$F\circ f $$ is a step function.

Proof: If f has representation: $$f=\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{j}\chi _{(\chi _{j-1,}\chi _{j})}+\sum_{j=1}^{n}f(x_{i})\chi_{\left [ x_{i}, x_{i}\right ]}$$ then $$F\circ f =\sum_{j=1}^{n}F(a_{j})\chi _{(\chi _{j-1,}\chi _{j})}+\sum_{j=1}^{n}(F\circ f)(x_{i})\chi_{\left [ x_{i}, x_{i}\right ]}$$ Where do we use that F(0)=0?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly is your definition of a "step function"? Also, by "interpretation", you probably mean "representation".

Comment: @PhoemueX yes, I meant representation, I edited my post. Step function is: $$f:R \mapsto R  $$ is called step function, if exist such a division that, $$P=\left \{ x_{0},....,x_{n} \right \} $$ and real numbers $$c_{1},....,c_{n} $$ so that $$f(x)=c_{j} $$ fo every x , $$x\in(x_{j-1},x_{j})$$ (j=1,....,n), while f(x)=0 fo every x whixh do not belong to $$\left [  x_{0},x_{n}\right ]$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need that $F\circ f(x)=0$ for all $x$ not belonging to the intervals $(x_{j-1},x_j)$. We know that $f(x)=0$ for all such $x$, and since $F(0)=0$ we have $F\circ f(x)=0$ for all such $x$ as well.

You have used this fact implicitly when going from $F(a_j \chi_{(x_{j-1},x_j)})$ to $F(a_j)\chi_{(x_{j-1},x_j)}$. This only holds if $F(0)=0$.

The problem if $F(0) \neq 0$ is that $F\circ f$ may have infinite support. I.e., we might not be able to find a finite number of finite intervals where $F \circ f$ is nonzero.

Comment: Thank you so much